# Gensim: Slow version of gensim.models.doc2vec is being used

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, gensim

My setup is as follows:

Python version: 3.6.0

Numpy version: 1.13.0

Scipy version: 0.19.0

Gensim version: 2.1.0

GCC Compiler version: 5.3.0

System: Windows 7, 64bit

I get the following error with the setup above

```
import gensim
>>>Slow version of gensim.models.doc2vec is being used
```

This makes the run time far too slow when training models on gensim. I feel there is some problem with the package versions I am using or how I installed them because: I had to install numpy using `pip`; I had to install scipy using `conda`; and I had to install gensim using `pip` again. The reason for this setup, is because if I try to install scipy using `pip`, I get the error

```
>>>ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

So I had to install scipy via `conda`. Also, if I try to install gensim using

`conda install gensim`

or

`conda update gensim`

it only installs version 1 - I have tried `conda install -c anaconda gensim=2.1.0` but I get the error

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
- gensim 2.1.0*
```

Numpy and Scipy work fine independently when I import them into a script - that is, they import fine and I can use all their functionality. However, when they are being used by Gensim, clearly there is a problem and I don't know why.

**Would anyone be able to advise possible fixes? Ideally I would like to keep all the latest versions of these packages if possible. Thank you in advance**

**NOTE: Gensim works fine with the "fast" version when I have Gensim version 1 installed and with the same versions of the dependencies above!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to do with the some underlying packages not being up to date. [Here](http://The%20problem%20is%20to%20do%20with%20the%20some%20underlying%20packages%20not%20being%20up%20to%20date.) I found the answer which work for me, which is in short:

Uninstall Gensim

```
sudo pip3 uninstall gensim
```

Install python3-dev build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev build-essential
```

Re-Install Gensim

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade gensim
```

Notes:

Instructions above are for systems where pip and apt-get are used to manage packages
pip3 is the python3 version of pip

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem (I'm running ubuntu).
I found out that if i'm using directly the version from github, the problem is fixed.

So there are 2 solutions: (first uninstall gensim using `pip uninstall gensim`)

- download and unzip the gensim zip file from gensim's [github page](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim), then CD to the folder of the zip content and run the command
  `python setup.py install`
- run this command `pip install git+https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim@master#egg=gensim`

I used the second and now I don't get the warnings